# PHP regex optional non-matching groups?

Tags: php, regex, date

I'm trying to make a date regex that allows years from 1900 to 2099, with the 19 or 20 optional.

I'm almost there, but I can't find a way to allow the 19 or 20 optional part.  Here's what I've got:

```
(?:20)(?:19)?[0-9][0-9]
```

Testing results:

```
String    preg_match     is this ok? 
======    ==========     ===========
55         yes             yes
1955       yes             yes
2055       yes             yes
201955     yes             no
```

Can someone help out?

Comment: It making the century optional really a good idea, considering the range?

Comment: Let's let curiousity overrule good sense in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
^(?:19|20)?\d{2}$
```

It says:

^ = Start of string

(?:19|20)? = Match 19 or 20 without capturing, zero or one times

\d{2} = 2 decimal digits

$ = End of string

Comment: Is that all? Actually have the `^$` but didn't include for simplicity.  All I needed was the pipe, thanks!  And the 2 decimal digits bit helps also, +1.

Comment: `^(19|20)?[0-9]{2}$` as normalized regexp syntax? Works.

Answer (score 1):

```
((20)|(19))?
```

the pipe means "OR" and they are optional because of the question mark